# Places where a website stores its data

Tags: python-2.7, python-requests

I have just started with Python Web scraping through Requests. This could be a broad question, I will try to make it as brief as possible.

I came through situation where sometimes an entire page source can be downloaded with `r.content` (where r is a response object of requests's get call)

Sometimes some part of the data is stored in json format... In files that can be accessed by deeply observing the get and post calls made.

However, I even found websites where the entire content is in DOM but part of it is neither in Page source nor in Json files.

I am wondering how many of such places can a website store a data in?
(Just the names, I am not looking for how to get there)

For these last type of websites, I have observed almost every requests call made, but couldn't find where the data is.

So are there any other place except the 2 mentioned above? Or those are the only two indicating I am not doing my job right of observing the requests call?

You may answer it in brief bullet points and I can take my study from there.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Lets assume we are talking only about HTML data. A web server could serve you data in many other formats (JSON/XML, etc.)

Please note that what I have described is generalisation, and like most generalisations, you could find exceptions that do not fit in it.

Broadly we could divide the type of data displayed (for the end user) into two categories

- Pre render
- Post render

**Pre render**

The entire HTML page is constructed at server-side and sent across to the client. Here, the JS side is concerned with the user interaction, and not with the structure of the data.

We are slowly moving away from this type of structure, but currently a large majority of all web pages uses this.

Web scraping is relatively easy here, as we can programatically pull the html page, and not bother about the javascript code that accompanies it.

a combination of `requests` and `beautifulsoup` should work in almost all of the cases (assuming that you could identify the general structure of the document).

**Post render**

Here the HTML page that is returned from the server is just a "skeleton" or placeholders for the actual data. The data is rendered by the accompanying JS code.

In such cases, if you fetch the source file via for eg., requests, you will get an empty shell, with no data in it.

for this if you inspect the calls made by a browser while rendering, (chrome's network tab or firefox's inspect tool or the more popular firebug), you will most likely see ajax requests that brings back the actual data from the server)

depending on how the requests are made, you could hit that ajax endpoint, and get the data in JSON.

you could use `response.json()` function to extract it into python-dicts.

In certain (rare) cases, there would not be an ajax call, but the HTML served from the server will still be a shell. The actual data is part of that file served, but stored as part of the JS code itself. This could be done for a variety of reasons, for example for dynamic data to be sent to static js files, or just to deter simple attempts of scraping the page.

One approach to scraping such pages would be to 'render' the page in a headless browser, which executes the JS code and returns an HTML that could be parsed via parsers like `beautifulsoup`

beautifulsoup has the ability to work with many [parsers](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#installing-a-parser), one of which is `html5lib`, which could solve this issue.

you could also look at [selenium](http://www.seleniumhq.org/) or [mechanize](http://wwwsearch.sourceforge.net/mechanize/)

or you could try parsing the js code yourself which might be faster.

Arriving at a conclusion as to what to use requires careful inspection of how the page is rendered on a browser. Even if you don't see an ajax request, the html that is served by the server need not be how the browser displays it.

A good way to start is by looking at the bare-html that is being served, by either downloading the page via `curl` or `requests.get` or simply rendering it in your browser with javascript disabled.

Good luck.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed response. +1 for that... It was indeed helpful. However, what I am looking to find is 3rd type of webpage where you finally opted for modules like selenium. I mean yes - they help a lot, but couldnt there be any way to get the results without having to use a browser and just keeping it as pure python? We now know html, json, xml. Are there others as well? Again, I am not looking for method to scrape but just where it could possibly store the data... Thanks again

Comment: you could look for [python-sellenium](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/) which needs a browser-driver and a machine with GUI, though there are ways to workaround that. 

you can start [here](https://realpython.com/blog/python/headless-selenium-testing-with-python-and-phantomjs/)

but try using beautiful-soup with html5lib first as that might be the fastest between the two options.